# Laravel undefined method has() - Many-Many getting records based on number of relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm attempting to use the Eloquent ORM in Laravel 4.0.x to do a query that compares a column in the row against the number of related models.

Let's say I've got the following models in a Many-Many relationship:

```
Class
-----
id
name
capacity

Student
-------
id
name
```

So say I want to find out which Classes have reached or exceeded their capacity.

It seems like, [according to the docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations), I should be able to use `has()` to do this query.

However, if I do:

```
$classes = Class::has('students', '>=', 50)->get();
```

I get a:

> BadMethodCallException saying **"Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::has()"**.

The example from the docs linked above uses a One-Many relationship mentioned earlier on the page. I've tried replicating this by making a `StudentLinks` model that each Class `hasMany()` of, and it still doesn't work for me. Same BadMethodCallException.

*Does has() actually exist in 4.0.x? It's in the docs...*

That isn't the only issue, though, because as near as I can tell, the `has()` method, even if it does exist, cannot access a column, although I don't have any proof of this. This is speculation due to the lack of information in the documentation.

What I want to be doing is basically:

```
$full_courses = Class::has('students', '>=', 'capacity')->get();
```

since the capacity is stored in the table I'm querying... but that obviously isn't working for me. After I've gotten the records, grabbing the actual count of students per class is trivial, but I want this in a single query so I can paginate it. Doing a filter after selecting makes it incredibly difficult for me to paginate this all manually, not using [Laravel's built-in Pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination).

Let's talk raw database, here: if I were to do this in SQL I would do:

```
SELECT class.id, class.name, class.capacity, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM classes AS class
LEFT JOIN class_student_pivot AS pivot ON class.id = pivot.class_id
GROUP BY class.id
HAVING class.capacity <= cnt
```

But I'd like my models.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's possible this was one of the new features added in 4.1.. there were some additions to querying relations, this might be one of them

Comment: Then it probably shouldn't be listed in the 4.0 documentation... I even checked the ChangeLog in detail trying to find where the method was added. I suppose the 'abandon ship' approach is in order here, but I'll wait to see if anyone tells me otherwise.

Comment: It has existed since [v4.0.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.0.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L533). You should be able to use DB::raw() to access a column, `Class::has('students', '>=', DB::raw('capacity'))->get()`

Comment: @JasonLewis It's odd, then, that I get a BadMethodCallException when attempting to use it. DB::raw() would solve the issue of accessing a column, though.

Comment: Show us your model then, has() was there for sure from 4.0